# Integrar e iterar clases

Tags: python

Estoy aprendiendo a usar python, he definido los diferentes elementos del programa pero no estoy seguro de como integrarlos, de forma tal de que itere las 20 veces que representan un turno, gracias de antemano.

Suponga que usted (el jugador) está parado en una acera recta muy larga que se extiende tanto delante como detrás de usted. Lanzas una moneda y lanzas un dado. Si la moneda sale cara, avanza varios pasos; sello significa retroceder varios pasos. El número de pasos se determina tirando el dado(1-6 pasos). Suponga que realiza una caminata aleatoria de 20 turnos (los que equivale a un juego). ¿A cuántos pasos del punto de partida terminarás? Encuentre un valor promedio para 100 juegos (20 turnos en cada juego).

```
from random import randint

class Coin:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def flip(self) -> str:
        return randint(1,2)

class Dice:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def roll(self) -> int: # get a random number form 1 -6
        return randint(1,6)

class Player:

    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self.position = 0
        self.name = name

    def update_position(self, delta: int):
        self.position += delta

    def make_turn(self, coin: Coin, dice: Dice):
        go_forward = Coin.flip
        go_forward == 1
        num_steps = dice.roll()

        if go_forward:
            delta = num_steps
        else:
            delta = -num_steps

        self.update_position(delta)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solamente tienes que hacer un bucle que se repita 20 veces. A continuación de las clases que has definido.

```
for turno in range(20):
    # Aqui dentro haces lo que quieres que el programa haga en cada turno. 
    # Por ejemplo crear una instancia de un jugador
    jugador = Player(input('Nombre de jugador: ')')
```

Answer (score 0):

Para realizar los 20 turnos seguidos de cada juego, puedes valerte de un ciclo for y encapsular el código de una partida de prueba en una función, de manera que puedas llamarla multiples veces.

Esta función sería la encargada de crear el jugador y realizar una partida de prueba completa y devolver la posición final del jugador.

Finalmente, para realizar los 100 juegos seguidos haría falta instanciar los objetos `Dice` y `Coin` y llamar 100 veces seguida a la rutina que hace el juego de prueba, para lo cual podemos valernos también de un for.

Por ejemplo:

```
def doTestPlay(playerNumber: int, coin: Coin, dice: Dice):
    player = Player("player" + str(playerNumber))
    for turn in range(20):
        player.make_turn(coin, dice)
    print("Resultado del " + player.name + ":",  player.position)
    return(player.position)

coin = Coin()    
dice = Dice()
testResults = []
for playerNumber in range(100):
    testResults.append(doTestPlay(playerNumber, coin, dice))
print("Resultados: ", testResults)
```

Como puedes ver, en la lista `testResults` quedan almacenados los resultados para que hagas con ellos los cálculos que corresponden y puedas responder al ejercicio completo.

Cuando logres ejecutar tu código, presta atención al método `make_turn`, tiene un par de bugs y por eso el jugador siempre se mueve hacia adelante.